# Azure B2C Custom Policy - Multi step sign up

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to create a 2 step sign up journey. I will write the user to the directory on the second step. If I comment out validation technical profile that writes the user to directory (AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail) from first step I get a server error when I execute the flow. What could be the issue? Can't the first step do nothing but collect input? I reduced the self asserted profile to only collect email, in reality I need a few claims to collect and hope to implement them once I get over with this roadblock.

Error when clicking "create account" button from sign in page
**The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.**

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithEmailStep1">

          <DisplayName>Email signup</DisplayName>

          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />

          <Metadata>

            <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>

            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.mholocalaccountsignupstep1</Item>

            <Item Key="language.button_continue">Next Step</Item>

            <Item Key="EnforceEmailVerification">False</Item>

          </Metadata>

          <CryptographicKeys>

            <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />

          </CryptographicKeys>

          <InputClaims>

            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />

          </InputClaims>

          <OutputClaims>

            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />

            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email"  **** ADDING OR REMOVING PartnerClaimType DOES NOT FIX THE ISSUE PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" ***** Required="true" />

            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />

            

          </OutputClaims>

         <!-- REMOVING THIS BLOCK ENDS UP WITH SERVER ERROR <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>

              <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail" />

          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>  -->

          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />

        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding [application insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/analytics-with-application-insights?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) will give you a more detailed error to investigate.

Check out the following samples for progressive profiling:

- [progressive profiling](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/progressive-profile)
- [split email verification and signup](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/split-email-verification-and-signup)

Comment: The issue is application insights is not giving any details. It just says "policyException". Thank you for the other links, pretty helpful

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Since "objectId" is not an output on this technical profile  journey fails with a server error. I am hoping Microsoft one day improves the error logging and troubleshooting. App Insights is on but it did not give me any detail other than "Microsoft.Cpim.Common.PolicyException" which we do not need to be logged, it is obvious there was a policy exception.
Is it too hard to log "objectId" is not part of any output from a validationtechnical profile etc....???